# ios7 adjusting iPodMusicPlayer volume

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I'm writing an app for ios7 that needs to control the volume of the built in music player or the master volume level in general. I've tried using the MediaPlayer.framework but not sure if that's right. I'm wondering what the best way to go about this is. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to Apple, in iOS7 setting `MPMusicPlayerController`'s `volume` is deprecated:

```
// The current volume of playing music, in the range of 0.0 to 1.0.
// This property is deprecated -- use MPVolumeView for volume control instead.
@property(nonatomic) float volume NS_DEPRECATED_IOS(3_0, 7_0);
```

Apple recommends using `MPVolumeView`, so I came up with this:

Add `volumeSlider` property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UISlider *volumeSlider;
```

Init `MPVolumeView` and add somewhere to your view (can be hidden, without frame, or empty because of `showsRouteButton = NO` and `showsVolumeSlider = NO`):

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [MPVolumeView new];
volumeView.showsRouteButton = NO;
volumeView.showsVolumeSlider = NO;
[self.view addSubview:volumeView];
```

Find and save reference to `UISlider`:

```
__weak __typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
[[volumeView subviews] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UISlider class]]) {
        __strong __typeof(weakSelf)strongSelf = weakSelf;
        strongSelf.volumeSlider = obj;
        *stop = YES;
    }
}];
```

Add target action for `UIControlEventValueChanged`:

```
[self.volumeSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(handleVolumeChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

And then detect volume changing (i.e. by the hardware volume controls):

```
- (void)handleVolumeChanged:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%s - %f", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, self.volumeSlider.value);
}
```

and also other way around, you can set volume by:

```
self.volumeSlider.value = < some value between 0.0f and 1.0f >;
```

Hope this helps (and that Apple doesn't remove MPVolumeSlider from MPVolumeView).

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:(use a value between 0.0 and 1.0)]
```

try this if you want to provide volume control

```
 MPVolumeView *myVolumeView =
    [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(70, 300, 200, 40)];
    [myVolumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:YES];
    [myVolumeView setShowsRouteButton:YES];
    [myVolumeView sizeToFit];
    [myVolumeView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor cyanColor]];
    CGAffineTransform trans = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * 0.5);
    myVolumeView.transform = trans;
    [moviePlayerContlr.view addSubview: myVolumeView];
```

**ALTERNATE:**

```
UISlider  * aSlider;
    aSlider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70, 200, 100, 40)];
    [aSlider setMaximumValue:0];
    [aSlider setMaximumValue:1];
    [aSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(aSliderAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [moviePlayerContlr.view addSubview:aSlider];

    UIImage *stetchTrack = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"faderTrack.png"]
                            stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:10.0 topCapHeight:0.0];
    [aSlider setThumbImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"faderKey.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aSlider setMinimumTrackImage:stetchTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aSlider setMaximumTrackImage:stetchTrack forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    CGAffineTransform tran = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI * -0.5);
    aSlider.transform = trans;



- (void)aSliderAction:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"%d",(int)[aSlider value]);;

[[MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer] setVolume:aSlider.value];
}
```

Comment: This is kind of what I've been trying. I'm trying to set it programatically based off of the user inputs not with a slider.

Comment: i stated here that these are the ways to set or control the volume. Look at the last method, instead of `aSlider.value` use user input. UISlider is a User input control... I think so...

Comment: MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];

[musicPlayer setVolume:currentVol];

if I print out printf("volume:%f", musicPlayer.volume); I'm getting really weird numbers like 0 or 1 billion

Comment: From the apple documents: Use an MPMusicPlayerController object, or music player, to play media items from the device iPod library. There are two types of music player:

The application music player plays music locally within your app. It is not aware of the iPod app’s now-playing item, nor does it affect the iPod state.

Comment: The iPod music player employs the built-in iPod app on your behalf. On instantiation, it takes on the current iPod app state, such as the identification of the now-playing item. If a user switches away from your app while music is playing, that music continues to play. The iPod app then has your music player’s most recently-set repeat mode, shuffle mode, playback state, and now-playing item.

Comment: so use  `([MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer])` instead of `([MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer])` and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Using iPodMusicPlayer would affect the actual iPod volume setting as well. If you want to avoid that, use this

```
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>
// ...
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = slider.value; //float value for volume
```

Or Try with:

```
MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = = [MPMusicPlayerController iPodMusicPlayer];
musicPlayer.volume = slider.value; //float value for volume
```

Comment: Accept the answer if it working. So other can take benefit from that.

Comment: This is what I've been trying forever and I thought it was working but when I debut and print the values out to the console I either get 0.00000 or a really big number.

Comment: Are you talking about the values for slider? You can round the values of slider as : http://stackoverflow.com/a/2822749/905514

Comment: No my slider value is between 0 and 1 when I print out slider.value, but when I printout printf("volume:%f", musicPlayer.volume); i get really weird numbers

Comment: Not getting your exact issues. May be MPVolumeView class can help you.

Comment: May be this can help: http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/controlling-system-output-volume-with-the-mpvolumeview-class-part-one/

Comment: Sorry if it's not clear I'm kinda new at this. I have a double that I'm getting from a UISlider. The double is between 0 and 1 so that's correct. But when I set it [musicPlayer setVolume:double] this right here should work but it's not. To debug I printed out in the console musicPlayer.volume and I get really big numbers or 0 which is weird because the double I set it to is between 0 and 1

Comment: Can you try that with executing application in IOS 6 and Volume method is deprecated in IOS 7.

Comment: I know it's deprecated but it should still work. If not there has to be some other way to do it