# volume is Deprecated in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, volume

How would I get around this?

```
volumeSlider setValue:[musicPlayer volume]];
```

&

```
- (IBAction)volumeSliderChanged:(id)sender
{
    [musicPlayer setVolume:volumeSlider.value];
}
```

Where '`volume`' and '`set volume`' is deprecated in iOS 7.0.  I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22129872/3127576) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3459720/3127576), but I was wondering if there's a simpler way?  My app works perfectly fine but I'm afraid this error will cause problems elsewhere.

All I need is for the user to drag the slider I have or use the hardware buttons to adjust the volume.

Thanks, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its deprecated it doesn't say so in the class reference.. says available for ios7

[image]

Heres what I do when I need to adjust volume in ios7 with a slider..

```
[avPlayer setVolume:self.volumeSlider.value];
```

Slider action..

```
- (IBAction)volumeControl:(id)sender {

    UISlider *mySlider = sender;
    [avPlayer setVolume:mySlider.value];

}
```